# Linq Contains Query from Table List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table with a list of keywords like

```
Waiter
Receptionist
Cleaner
Painter
```

And I have another table that has a Job Title.

I want a query that tells me if any of the words in the first table are contained in a specific Job Title in the second table

Im wondering if this is possible without looping over every row in the first table.

Comment: You should be able to do a `.Contains()` within the `Where()`.  Can you post the current query that you're running?

Comment: If you need the whole list of matches, use inner join. If you only need the bool value of existence, add `Any()` to the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as reference and modify as needed.

```
SecondTable.Where(a => FirstTable.Any(b => b.Keyword == a.Keyword))
```